# Lagrangian with constraint Greater than Zero (NOT 'greater than or equal to').

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Problem statement:
$$\underset{D}{\text{argmin} }\lVert D\Sigma - G \rVert_F^2 \text{ with constraint } D>O$$

$D$ and $\Sigma$ are positive diagonal, therefore the constraint interprets $\text{diag}(D)>0$ vector.

I have seen $\ge$ and $\le$ in examples, but my concern is having $>$ in this constraint since $D$ is positive.

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just ignore the strict inequality and solve as $\geq$. If your answer “accidentally” satisfies $>$ then you are done. Else add $\epsilon$ to the components, now you satisfy the constraint and are arbitrarily close to the infimum. “Arbitrarily close” is often the most you can hope for when optimizing over an open set. For example take G=0 and $\Sigma=I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a free minimum; then we do the calculation without any conditions.

Let $f(D)=tr((D\Sigma-G)(\Sigma D-G^T)),D=diag(d_{i}),\Sigma=diag(\sigma_i),G=[g_{i,j}]$. Let $\Delta$ be the set of diagonal matrices. The derivative is

$Df_D:H\in\Delta\mapsto 2tr(H^T(D\Sigma -G)\Sigma)$. If $f$ admits a local extremum in $D$, then, for every $H\in \Delta$,  $Df_D(H)=0$; that is equivalent to:

for every $i$, $((D\Sigma -G)\Sigma)_{i,i}=0$ or (since $\sigma_{i}>0$),

for every $i$, $(D\Sigma-G)_{i,i}=0$ or, for every $i$, $d_i\sigma_i=g_{i,i}$, that is,

for every $i$, $d_i=g_{i,i}/\sigma_{i,i}$. In particular, if $f$ reaches its minimum in $D$, then, necessarily, $signum(d_i)=signum(g_{i,i})>0$.

$\textbf{Conclusion}$. If there is $i$, s.t. $g_{i,i}\leq 0$, then $\min(f)$ does not exist on $D>0$.

If, for every $i$, $g_{i,i}>0$, then $\min(f)$ is reached for $D=diag(g_{i,i}/\sigma_{i})$ and $f(D)=\sum_{i\not= j}{g_{i,j}}^2$.

EDIT. Of course, we can do the job directly, canceling the entries of the diagonal of $D\Sigma-G$ (because the other entries are always $-g_{i,j}$).